# Shell script working if typed line by line, not working if put in a file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the following shell script:

```
channels=(prod)
for f in aaa bbb ccc
do
  channels=("${channels[@]}" $f)
done
echo $channels
```

What it does: initialize an array that contains "prod". Using a for loop to append "aaa", "bbb" and "ccc" to the array.

The wired thing is, if I type this block of code line by line into my terminal, it works as expected. But if I put the code into a file, and execute the file, the appending part is not working.

Here is the screenshot of me typing it line by line: 
[image]

Here is the file that I put the code in: 
[image]

Here is the execution of the file:

[image]

Comment: You're running `zsh` in your terminal, but running your script with `bash`. Compare `zsh test.sh` vs `bash test.sh`

Comment: Hi, I just tried it on my linux, bash v.4.3.48 on Linux Mint 18 and I get the same results in a terminal window (SHELL=bash) or in a script `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks! It was because bash an zsh!